# Why Does the Form on this Page Only Work Once?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, jquery-mobile

[Here's the Form in Question](http://dealdynamite.com/phonerecyclers)

I'm new to jQuery Mobile, so I suspect this issue has something to do with the JS jQuery Mobile runs.

The form seems to behave as expected the first time through. Subsequent submissions seem to do nothing...and there is also mildly annoying animation after each submission.

EDIT: You can enter "test" for an example query.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Phone Price Look-up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Price Finder
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="search-form-container">
                    <form name="search-form">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <label for="search_term">
                                    Enter Model Number:
                                </label>
                                <input id="search_term" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <input id="search-form-submit" type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">
                <h2>
                    www.thephonerecyclers.com
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false; // don't really know what this does.
                $('#search-form-submit').click(function() {
                    var searchTerm = $('#search_term').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax/search.php',
                        data: {search_term: searchTerm},
                        success: function(response) {
                            response = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (!response.success) {
                                alert('no phone found');
                            } else {
                                var phoneInfo = JSON.parse(response.response);
                                alert(phoneInfo[0].manufacturer + ' ' + phoneInfo[0].name + ' (' + phoneInfo[0].model_no + ')' + '\n$' + phoneInfo[0].price);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            //handle error
                            alert('error doing ajax, mate');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here. I don't click on links in questions.

Comment: It didn't work for me even the first time. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What's not working?  The behavior looks identical to me every time.  And FireBug shows the request and response every time.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error(s) that I inadvertently created right after posting my question. They are gone now. The original issue I posted about remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because much of JQuery mobile utilizes hash routing navigation and dynamically created content, normal event handlers may not be enough. In your example, you are posting a form to a new hash route and rebuilding the page without a reload.  The newly created objects are not included in any of the event handlers you previously defined.

Instead of defining the click handler as you did:

```
$('#search-form-submit').click(function() {
```

You should utilize the jQuery "on" function.  Because you are including an older version of JQuery, use the "live" function that serves a similar purpose like this:

```
 $('#search-form-submit').live("click", function(){
```

By binding the event in this manner, any dynamically created content should also be included by the handler.

Comment: I had just wondered before I came back to check for new answers whether the handler was not attaching the second time around. You confirmed my suspicion and provided a working solution. Thanks. Only thing I wonder is whether it is better to use `live('click', ...)` or maybe create a JS function that wraps the needed AJAX functionality and attach it to the button in the HTML itself: `<input id="search-form-submit" type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Submit" onclick="doAjax()"/>`

Comment: I prefer handlers over inline code but as far as best practice I am not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your alert in your ajax success function has syntax errors, I think this is what keeps it from working:

you have:

```
 alert(phoneInfo[0].manufacturer +' '+ phoneInfo[0].name +(+ +phoneInfo[0].model_no+ +)+ +'\n$'+ phoneInfo[0].price);
```

should be:

```
 alert(phoneInfo[0].manufacturer +' '+ phoneInfo[0].name +'('+phoneInfo[0].model_no+')\n$'+ phoneInfo[0].price);
```

Comment: Whoops, I just had added those parenthesis before I posted my question. It's fixed now, but does not address the issue I posted about.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the syntax errors in this line:

```
alert(phoneInfo[0].manufacturer +' '+ phoneInfo[0].name +(+ +phoneInfo[0].model_no+ +)+ +'\n$'+ phoneInfo[0].price);
```

e.g.:

```
alert(phoneInfo[0].manufacturer+' '+phoneInfo[0].name+'('+phoneInfo[0].model_no+')'+'\n$'+phoneInfo[0].price);
```

Comment: Whoops, I just had added those parenthesis before I posted my question. It's fixed now, but does not address the issue I posted about.